# set a formula in excel ignoring culture

Tags: excel, excel-interop

my problem is that I use Interop to set formulas in excel but my formula is English, my excel is Portuguese Brazil, so when I try to define the formula, an error occurs.
Have any way of defining a culture for my workbook or ignore the Culture?

```
 const string ValidaNascimento = "=IF((INT((NOW()-E{0})/366,25))>65;FALSE;TRUE)";

 rng = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[row, 6], oSheet.Cells[row, 6]);

 rng.Formula = ValidaNascimento;//string.Format(ValidaNascimento, row);
```

Comment: show the part of your code where you do so... one more thing- check `.Formula` and `.FormulaLocal` properties which could provide solution you need.

Comment: const string ValidaNascimento = "=IF((INT((NOW()-E{0})/366,25))>65;FALSE;TRUE)";
rng = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[row, 6], oSheet.Cells[row, 6]);
                   rng.Formula = string.Format(ValidaNascimento, row);

Comment: your function `"=if(...)` is incorrect. it's not language issue. One error- use `point` instead of `comma` to separate decimal part of numbers`. Second, check `e{0}` which is not defined in you example.

Answer (score 0):

International (language independant) formulas use

- English names (as you have)
- `.` for decimal
- `,` to seperate parameters

So use

```
ValidaNascimento = "=IF((INT((NOW()-E{0})/366.25))>65,FALSE,TRUE)"
```

Comment: Not sure what your `E{0}` is, so can't comment on that